# Laurent series expansion of function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-z}$ in powers of $z-i$ in region of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I need a little help with this one. This $z-i$ confuses me.

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-z}=\frac{1}{z(z-1)}=-\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z-1}$$

So, singularities are $z=0$ and $z=1$. What regions do I have to consider when expanding in series?

And is this correct: if it was asked "in powers of $z$", in this particular case would we expand series in these areas $|z|<1$ and $|z|>1$?

There is nothing more in example text.
Any help very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you region of convergence is centered at $z=i$ and have singularities at $z=0,1$, therefore you need to consider the following regions:

1. $|z-i|<1$ (note:function is analytic in this region so you know the Laurent series will be simply ....)
2. $1<|z-i|<\sqrt{2}$
3. $|z-i|>\sqrt{2}$

This way you will be able to take care of both the singularities.

**Now for the first region:**
Consider
$$f(z)=-\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z-1}=-\frac{1}{z-i+i}+\frac{1}{z-i+i-1}=-\frac{1}{i\left(1+\frac{z-i}{i}\right)}+\frac{1}{(i-1)\left(1+\frac{z-i}{i-1}\right)}.$$
Since we are in the first region, therefore 
$$\left|\frac{z-i}{i}\right| < 1 \text{ and } \left|\frac{z-i}{i-1}\right|< 1.$$
Thus we can use the following geometric series expansion to expand both terms.
$$\frac{1}{1+w}=1-w+w^2-w^3+\dotsb \qquad (|w|<1),$$
and get
$$f(z)=\frac{-1}{i}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\left(\frac{z-i}{i}\right)^k+\frac{1}{i-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\left(\frac{z-i}{i-1}\right)^k.$$
Similarly you can try the other two regions. For example for the second region you may want to start with
$$f(z)=-\frac{1}{z-i+i}+\frac{1}{z-i+i-1}=-\frac{1}{(z-i)\left(1+\frac{i}{z-i}\right)}+\frac{1}{(i-1)\left(1+\frac{z-i}{i-1}\right)}.$$
**Observe that since we are in the second region**, therefore
$$\left|\frac{i}{z-i}\right| < 1 \text{ and } \left|\frac{z-i}{i-1}\right|< 1.$$
Hopefully you will be able to take it from here.

Comment: That was really helpful, solved my doubts. Thank you very much!

Comment: Only one more question. In second region you wrote $$\left|\frac{i}{z-i}\right| < 1 \text{ and } \left|\frac{z-i}{i-1}\right|< 1$$
isn't it $$\left|\frac{i}{z-i}\right| < 1 \text{ and } \left|\frac{i-1}{z-1}\right|< 1?$$

Comment: in the second region $|z-i|<\sqrt{2}$ and $|i-1|=\sqrt{2}$. Hence what I wrote is correct.